# SQL Server : how do do HAVING criteria on bit value

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below code demonstrates the problem I'm trying to solve. Basically I only want to select transactions where a customer has never purchased a product where isActive is now  0.

I tried using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING MIN(p.isActive) = 1` to get only the customers associated with active products. This query is close but `MIN` does not like bit type. How can I do this?

The goal is to only see transactions associated with just Lisa and Fred. Bill should be removed from the results since one of his transactions is currently associated with a InActive product.

```
CustomerName    ProductName (No column name)
Bill    Cheerios    1
Lisa    Cheerios    1
Bill    Corn Flakes 1
Fred    Corn Flakes 1
Bill    Granola     0
```

ERROR: Operand data type bit is invalid for min operator.

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer (
    CustomerId int,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100),
    Address nvarchar(100),
)
INSERT INTO #Customer
VALUES (1, 'Bill', '123 1st St'),
       (2, 'Fred', '111 Market St'),
       (3, 'Lisa', '01 Boulevard')

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    ProductId int,
    ProductName nvarchar(100),
    isActive bit
)
INSERT INTO #Product
VALUES (1, 'Corn Flakes', 1),
       (2, 'Cheerios', 1),
       (3, 'Granola', 0)

CREATE TABLE #TransactionLog (
    LogId int,
    ProductId int,
    CustomerId int,
    Amount float
)
INSERT INTO #TransactionLog
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (2, 2, 1, 2.40),
       (3, 3, 1, 1.80),
       (4, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (5, 1, 2, 2.00),
       (6, 2, 3, 2.40)

SELECT * from #Customer
SELECT * from #Product
SELECT * from #TransactionLog

SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    MIN(p.isActive)
FROM #TransactionLog t
join #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId
join #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName
HAVING
    MIN(p.isActive) = 1

DROP TABLE #Customer
DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #TransactionLog
```

I'm not sure why but when I try `HAVING MIN(CAST(p.isActive AS INT)) = 1`, I still get 2 rows of data associated with Bill. I'd like to eliminate Bill from the result.

```
Bill    Cheerios    1
Lisa    Cheerios    1
Bill    Corn Flakes 1
Fred    Corn Flakes 1
```

Comment: why `MIN(p.isActive) = 1` when it is either 0 or 1?  Do you mean to have some sort of a count there?

Comment: If it doesn't work on bit, have you tried casting to int?

Comment: Cast to int doesn't seem to work. I can still see Bill in the results.

Comment: It looks to me like Bill is the customer ID for the first two rows of the trans table and those are active flagged products? Am I wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `p.isActive = 1` in the where clause?  With the sample data you provide it will return exactly the same results for `CustomerName`, `ProductName`,

Comment: `INNER JOIN #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId AND  p.isActive = 1` might be better (avoids the WHERE/GROUP BY )...

Comment: You're grouping by `ProductName` so your `having` condition isn't seeing all the Bill rows together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with data as (
    SELECT
        c.CustomerName, p.ProductName,
        count(case when p.isActive = 0 then 1 end)
            over (partition by c.CustomerID) as countInactive 
    FROM #TransactionLog t
        inner join #Product  p on t.ProductId  = p.ProductId
        inner join #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
)
select * from data where countInactive = 0;
```

You can accomplish it with `min() over ()` as well if you prefer that logic.

Comment: Works like a champ!

Comment: This is better than mine with the NOT EXITS sub query mess

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert to a number:

```
HAVING MIN(CONVERT(tinyint, p.isActive)) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - casting to INT as suggested in my comment:

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer (
    CustomerId int,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100),
    Address nvarchar(100),
)
INSERT INTO #Customer
VALUES (1, 'Bill', '123 1st St'),
       (2, 'Fred', '111 Market St'),
       (3, 'Lisa', '01 Boulevard')

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    ProductId int,
    ProductName nvarchar(100),
    isActive bit
)
INSERT INTO #Product
VALUES (1, 'Corn Flakes', 1),
       (2, 'Cheerios', 1),
       (3, 'Granoloa', 0)

CREATE TABLE #TransactionLog (
    LogId int,
    ProductId int,
    CustomerId int,
    Amount float
)
INSERT INTO #TransactionLog
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (2, 2, 1, 2.40),
       (3, 3, 1, 1.80),
       (4, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (5, 1, 2, 2.00),
       (6, 2, 3, 2.40)

SELECT * from #Customer
SELECT * from #Product
SELECT * from #TransactionLog

SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    MIN(CAST(p.isActive AS int))
FROM #TransactionLog t
join #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId
join #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName
HAVING
    MIN(CAST(p.isActive AS INT)) = 1

DROP TABLE #Customer
DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #TransactionLog
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a join instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer (
    CustomerId int,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100),
    Address nvarchar(100),
)
INSERT INTO #Customer ( CustomerId, CustomerName, Address )
VALUES (1, 'Bill', '123 1st St'),
       (2, 'Fred', '111 Market St'),
       (3, 'Lisa', '01 Boulevard')

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    ProductId int,
    ProductName nvarchar(100),
    isActive bit
)
INSERT INTO #Product (ProductId, ProductName, isActive)
VALUES (1, 'Corn Flakes', 1),
       (2, 'Cheerios', 1),
       (3, 'Granoloa', 0)

CREATE TABLE #TransactionLog (
    LogId int,
    ProductId int,
    CustomerId int,
    Amount float
)
INSERT INTO #TransactionLog (LogId, ProductId ,CustomerId ,Amount )
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (2, 2, 1, 2.40),
       (3, 3, 1, 1.80),
       (4, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (5, 1, 2, 2.00),
       (6, 2, 3, 2.40)

--SELECT * from #Customer
--SELECT * from #Product
--SELECT * from #TransactionLog

SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    p.isActive
FROM #TransactionLog t
INNER JOIN #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId AND  p.isActive = 1
INNER JOIN #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName

DROP TABLE #Customer
DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #TransactionLog
```

EDIT: PER NOTE, Get rid of Bill if he every ordered an inactive product

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer (
    CustomerId int,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100),
    Address nvarchar(100),
)
INSERT INTO #Customer ( CustomerId, CustomerName, Address )
VALUES (1, 'Bill', '123 1st St'),
       (2, 'Fred', '111 Market St'),
       (3, 'Lisa', '01 Boulevard')

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    ProductId int,
    ProductName nvarchar(100),
    isActive bit
)
INSERT INTO #Product (ProductId, ProductName, isActive)
VALUES (1, 'Corn Flakes', 1),
       (2, 'Cheerios', 1),
       (3, 'Granoloa', 0)

CREATE TABLE #TransactionLog (
    LogId int,
    ProductId int,
    CustomerId int,
    Amount float
)
INSERT INTO #TransactionLog (LogId, ProductId ,CustomerId ,Amount )
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (2, 2, 1, 2.40),
       (3, 3, 1, 1.80),
       (4, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (5, 1, 2, 2.00),
       (6, 2, 3, 2.40)

--SELECT * from #Customer
--SELECT * from #Product
--SELECT * from #TransactionLog

SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    p.isActive
FROM #TransactionLog AS t
INNER JOIN #Product AS p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId   
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM #TransactionLog AS ts 
        INNER JOIN #Product AS ps 
            ON ts.ProductId = ps.ProductId 
                AND ps.isActive = 0 
        WHERE ts.CustomerId = t.CustomerId
    )
INNER JOIN #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    p.isActive

DROP TABLE #Customer
DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #TransactionLog
```

Comment: Bill still shows up in the result. Since Bill has had a transaction in the past that where isActive=0, I'd like to eliminate Bill from all results

Comment: But isActive = 1 in your data, SO we can fix that with a sub query perhaps ON ANY  inactive Bill purchased to eliminate him